# Change the background color of a Context Menu using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am implementing UIContextMenu on a UICollectionViewCell. Inside the UICollectionViewCell there is a button with a radius of 15. When I tap on a UICollectionViewCell this is the result
[image]. What I want is just the button without the white background. I already tried `UICollectionViewCell.backgroundColor = .clear` and seems not working. If anyone can help me thanks!

Comment: How did you change the color of "Remove"? Its fixed to black in my case!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm thinking of using a custom menu

Comment: @CesarQuiroga I have not. I'm sorry. Let me know if you found one.

Answer (score 3):

Add `let identifier = "\(indexPath.row)" as NSString` in your `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?` function.

Put that identifier in the `UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: identifier, previewProvider: previewProvider, actionProvider: actionProvider)` init.

Next add this func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
        guard
            let identifier = configuration.identifier as? String,
            let index = Int(identifier),
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? YourCell

              else {
                return nil
            }
        return UITargetedPreview(view: cell.YourButton)
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the index path as the identifier of the `UIContextMenuConfiguration` doing `indexPath as NSCopying`, and you don't need to convert the row value into a String and back.

Answer (score 1):

You have `UIPreviewParameters` where you can change `backgroundColor` easily.

Comment: To get the whole context regarding this, here is an example:   **let params = UIPreviewParameters()
        params.backgroundColor = .clear
        return UITargetedPreview(view: cell.bgView, parameters: params)**

Answer (score -3):

I think in your `UICollectionViewCell`, call `contentView.backgroundColor = .clear` will work.

[image]

Can you provide further info ? Because my code works.

Comment: Did you implement Context Menu? And long pressed it?